# VFAT FS Sync/Flush Behaviour

Tags: filesystems, mount, fstab, fat, vfat

In order to increase the life of my VFAT flash drives, I have them set to mount as `async`.  One of these drives sometimes deals with large data changes, and as a result, the writes that occur on `umount` takes longer than 120 seconds, which causes the kernel's `task blocked for more than 120 seconds` error and makes it impossible to cleanly unmount the drive.

Is there a way to force the IO writes to happen without unmounting the drive?  Ideally I could flush the writes, then unmount with nothing left to do (which should only take a few seconds).  I'm aware of the `flush` option for mounting fat drives, but is this still detrimental to the life of the drive?